# Rhasspy Docker Container Cannot Access Microphone or Speakers

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I have started a linux container running rhasspy in docker (using docker desktop for windows) following their installation guide. I then open the container on the assigned port in firefox, but when I attempt to set up audio input or output the only option is "default device" in the dropdown menu. This device does not work and rhasspy is unable to use audio input or output.

I am using rhasspy and docker on a windows 10 machine, and I assume that the problem is that there is trouble with docker having permissions or passing them along to rhasspy. I would appreciate a work around to give rhasspy access or another suggestion for how to run it in such a way that it can actually be used.

So far I have run the Command Prompt line below and successfully created a rhasspy linux container. I expected access to the audio inputs and outputs from the --privileged and --device flags I used

```
docker run -d -p 12101:12101 --name rhasspy1 --restart unless-stopped -v "/.config/rhasspy/profiles:/profiles" --device "/dev/snd:/dev/snd" --privileged rhasspy/rhasspy --user-profiles /profiles --profile en
```